# How to send data between two ESP32's over same LAN?

Tags: http, arduino, wifi, esp32, espressif-idf

I want to send data(I think I can achieve it sending http requests) between two ESP's that are connected to the same LAN. **I don't want to use one as an access point!** I have one esp that is acting as a homekit device, and I want to send data(for example, sensor readings) to it from another esp. I've seen many tutorials where one device is acting as an access point, but that's not what I need. I also don't really need to access the esp data directly from my laptop, so I believe I don't need the html page. I would appreciate any help, code, or any existing tutorials, because I didn't find a single one.

Comment: why would you use http between two esp32? start a TCP server, connect to it with a socket from the other esp32, there accept a socket from the server and everything you write in one of the sockets you can read from the socket on the other end

Answer (score 1):

Configuring one ESP as an AP is only done for convenience. You can configure both of them in STA (station) mode and they will connect to, e.g. your phone hotspot or your wifi router.

Connected to the same hotspot, they are on the same network, and they will be able to communicate with each other (unless the hotspot is configured to not allow this ... ). The tricky part will most likely be for the "client" to determine the IP address of the "server" in order to create the connection.

If you have admin access to the hotspot, you can cheat and hard code the IP addresses (assuming that the hotspot will assign the same IP address to the device the next time it sees it.)

It's also not difficult to use mdns (aka bonjour), which allows a network device to assign itself a local hostname. So you can name one ESP ("myserver") which allows the ESP running the client code to connect to "http://myserver.local"